Can you provide me an example of quantifiers with their scopes overlapping?

Screenshot comes from Rosen's Discrete Math Textbook.
Scope (as per textbook): The part of a logical expression to which a quantifier is applied is called the scope of this quantifier.
The textbook gives the example of $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x)) \lor \forall xR(x)$ and explains that scope of the first quantifer doesn't overlap with the the scope of the 2nd quantifier since the first quantifier's scope is limited to $P(x)\land Q(x)$, whereas the 2nd quantifier's scope is limited to $R(x)$.
Because the scope's don't overlap, textbook says that we could express it using 2 different variables x & y, as $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x)) \lor \forall yR(y)$. However, they also mention:

The reader should be aware that in common usage, the same letter is often used to represent variables bound by different quantifiers with scopes that do not overlap.

Kindly could someone provide a good example of an expression where the quantifiers' scopes do overlap?

Please do not rely on images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post.  See here for some of the reasons why.

@ArturoMagidin just edited the post. Does this work out?

A simple example would be $\forall x \exists y (x < y)$. Here the scopes of both quantifiers overlap on $x < y$, hence we must use different variables.

Here is an example of a statement where quantifiers overlap and the symbol is repeated.
Claim. $-1$ is the only odd integer.
Proof. Suppose that $a$ is an odd integer. By definition, there exists an integer $a$ such that $a=2a+1$. By algebra, $a=-1$.
This is, of course, false. The problem is that the letter used for the existential quantifier was the same as the universal quantifier surrounding the claim.

Sorry, I'm confused on this example and proof. Why are we saying "By definition, there exists an integer a such that a = 2a + 1"? Kindly if you could type out you're quantifier example using symbols, I'd be grateful.
.

I guess I don't understand your question very well, then. An expression with two quantifiers, using the same variable, in which the scopes overlap would be ambiguous. That's what I was trying to illustrate with my example.

The basic fact is that a quantified variable can be renamed without issue (we can prove it); i.e. $∀x(x>0)$ has the same meaning of $∀y(y>0)$. i.e.they are logically equivalent.
Thus, renaming is allowed, provided that we do not "capture" free variables.
That is $∃x(x+y=1)$ is not the same as $∃y(y+y=1)$.
This means that, if the quantifier applies to separate parts, like in $∀xP(x) ∨ ∃xQ(x)$, we can use the same variable $x$ without problem.
But it can be a good practice to avoid it, using the equivalent form $∀xP(x) ∨ ∃yQ(y)$.
